# knockoutjs 'foreach' bind can not get a property which is defined as a class?

Tags: binding, foreach, knockout.js

I'm new to use Knockoutjs

I have a viewModel defind as below:

```
// this is a subclass
var Order = {
        selfdata: {
            id : ko.observable(),
            goodsName : ko.observable(''),
            color : ko.observable(''),
            size : ko.observable(''),
            count: ko.observable(''),
            orderDate: ko.observable(''),
            remarks: ko.observable('')
        },
    }
   // this is a viewModel
   function ShoppingCar() {
        var self = this;
        self.orders = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.show = function (msg) {
            return msg.id;
        }

        //init
        $.get('/Shopping/GetOrders', null, function (data) {
            var items = $.map(data, function (item) { return Order.init(item) });// I write a init function to init order
            self.orders(items);
        });
    }
//then I use Knockoutjs foreach binding as below:
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="e" data-divider-theme="d">
 <!-- ko foreach: orders -->
     <li data-role="list-divider" data-bind="text: $data.selfdata.id">//!I get null value here</li>

     <li><a href="#">
        <h3 data-bind="text: $data.isValid"></h3>
        <p><strong data-bind="text: $data.selfdata.color">//! here has null value too!</strong></p>
        <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>12:14</strong>PM</p>
        </a></li>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

So, my question is, how can I display `order.selfdata` in a ko's foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just putting:

```
selfdata.id
```

Also, have you debugged and made sure that you are actually populating the Orders object correctly?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I debug in chrome and find a Stupid Mistake. When I get the json from server the property name is Id,Name... but in js I use id,name...O,MY GOD!

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your strong tag.  Its getting wiped out by the comments

```
<p><strong data-bind="text: $data.selfdata.color">//! here has null value too!</strong></p>
```

should be

```
<p><strong data-bind="text: $data.selfdata.color"></strong></p>
```

You also don't need the $data.  selfdata.color should be working fine, assuming the data is actually being passed into the observable correctly.

If fixing the comments and removing $data don't work I would use a browser debugger to check and see what data is actually in the observable object.